# How to do virtual methods on objectID in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My goal is calculate the average ratings for every product that is presented, I tried to do custom methods and it doesn't work

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    reviews: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review'}],
});

const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rating: { type: Number, default: 0}
});

ProductSchema.methods.calculateReviews = function (next) {
      var rating = 0
      this.reviews.map((review) => {
        rating += review.rating;
      });

      rating = rating / product.reviews.length;
      return rating;
 };
```

Should I use virtual?

Answer (score 0):

in this case virtual is a good  idea

```
ProductSchema
.virtual('rating')
.get(function() {
    var rating = 0
    this.reviews.map((review) => {
        rating += review.rating;
    });

    rating = rating / this.reviews.length;
    return rating;
});
```

Comment: if reviews array is empty, then rating will always be null?